# Why don't reg expressions from regexlib.com work in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I found a regex on http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=73
It's for matching a telephone number with international code like so:

```
^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$
```

When using with PHP's preg_match, the expression fails? Why is that?

Comment: What's the PHP code you're trying to use?

Comment: You should use this site's code formatting features instead of HTML (e.g., `<code>` tags).  That's why the backslashes were getting dropped.

Answer (score 3):

You need to surround it with `/` delimiters:

```
preg_match('/^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_\- \(\)]*$/', $phoneNumber)
```

And make sure you don't leave out the backslashes (`\`).

Comment: Actually you can use any delimiter, you only need to match the starting delimiter with the ending one. I use things like '@', or '!' as delimiters all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Because `preg_match` expects the regex to be delimited, usually with slashes (but, as correctly noted below, other characters are possible as long as they are matched):

```
preg_match('/^(\(?\+?[0-9]*\)?)?[0-9_ ()-]*$/', $subject)
```

Apart from that, the original regex was copied wrong - several characters were unescaped. The original on regexlib has a few warts, too (some characters were escaped needlessly).

Comment: The regex can be delimited with things other than slashes.   You just have to make sure you match 'em and escape them if they appear in the regex.  Unfortunately, I can't find the reference in the manual.

Comment: yeah I copied it from there, but the backslashes didn't make it, thanks. What characters where escaped needlessly??

Comment: The parentheses and the dash inside the character class - if you put the dash at the start or the end of the class, it doesn't have to be escaped; the parentheses don't have to be escaped at all.